# How to create glossy icons with cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, effects

Being a newcomer to cycles, I couldn't find a shader that does such gloss type which I used to make using Diffuse > Ramp in blender internal .

[image: Colour ramp]

So what shader should I use in Cycles to achieve that knowing that the Glossy shader reflects the surrounding environment and not just light and it doesn't have that "Ramp" option.
The desired goal is an effect similar to this:
[image: Glossy icons]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple node set up that should get you close to what you are looking for.

[image]

Also you need a light to reflect, so I added a plane and put an emission shader on it.

[image]

Comment: This is pretty close to what I want, it only lacks the "ramp" option, otherwise , it does the job

Comment: In Cycles there is a node called "Color Ramp" just hook that into the diffuse or glossy shader. Depending on the look you are trying to get.